# Is S->E+S|E, E->number|(S) same as S->number|(S+S)?

Tags: compilers

I'm reading https://ilyasergey.net/CS4212/_static/lectures/PLDI-Week-07-more-parsing.pdf

On page 11, there's the definition of Sum Grammar:

```
S -> E + S | E
E -> number | (S)
```

Just wondering if this grammar same as follows:

```
S -> number | (S+S)
```

Comment: will your grammar be able to generate $num + num + num...+ num$?

Comment: @ArunMadhav Awesome thanks, please make it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modified grammar:

1. We cannot generate $number + number + number....+ number$, as every operation will have a parenthesis associated with it.
2. Redundant parenthesis: $number + number$, we  will have to describe it as $(number + number)$ here the parenthesis are redundant.

If you modify the grammar to:

$S\rightarrow S+S$ $|(S)|$ $number$

It will solve both the issues mentioned
and generate the same language as Sum Grammar but it's an ambiguous grammar and doesn't have the properties of Sum grammar(right-to-left associativity)